# Laravel global middleware can't get session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

```
 protected $middleware = [
     \App\Http\Middleware\Syspoint::class,
]

use Session;
class Syspoint
{
    echo \Session::get('syspoint');
}
```

I have a middleware required run everytime when page request, the middleware contain session.

I place inside of `protected $middleware`, but global middleware not able to get session.

Comment: what version of laravel?

Comment: i use laravel 5.3.23

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are calling Session but it is not already started.

If you need Session inside your middleware you have to put it in the property `protected $middlewareGroups` under the key `web` and after the call to StartSession, i.e.:

```
 protected $middlewareGroups
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Syspoint::class,
```

Comment: It will run every web request, api, by default, dont have session

Comment: Very useful, thanks!

Comment: I am using Laravel 9.x version and `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` line is already written as you suggested in Kernal.php file but still not able to use `Session` in any middleware.

Answer (score 0):

dparoli's answer correct but not exactly! Because this middleware will run every web request!

How about running only under some route? Here is how;

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'sys-point' => \App\Http\Middleware\Syspoint::class,
];
```

Then on your route define new middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','sys-point'], 'namespace' => 'YourControllers'], function()
{
}
```