# why laravel can not get session in middleware?

Tags: laravel, session, middleware

I set the session in the controller and want check the session in the middleware,but i can not get session in the middleware.

```
   $phoneCookie = $request->cookie('phone');

    $session = Session::get($phoneCookie);


    // can not get session
    Log::debug($session['phone']);

    Log::debug($session['token']);
```

Comment: That is correct. You cannot get the session in the middleware.

Comment: Why you want to use session in middleware?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877799/laravel-global-middleware-cant-get-session/42877954) similar question.

Comment: @PankajMakwana ,cause I want check some cookie  whether it is correct by session .If can not use session in the middleware,should I use cache instead session?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Are you really really sure ? If that was true ,I will find another way .