# Laravel 5.8 419 error / Auth user not available after login

Tags: laravel, session

Problem description: after login I receive a 419 page, also session token keeps changing which causes `Auth::check()` to fail. Database token stays the same but on Laravel side session token keeps changing.

Locally it works this only occurs on live server that this happens.

What I have tried:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
composer update
composer dump-autoload
create fresh installation copy fresh one into old version and dont overwrite
changed cache from file to database
confirmed `/public/index.php` is correct
SESSION_LIFETIME = 120
SESSION_DOMAIN set to domain
generated new app key
checked file permissions
```

Session token changes:
[image: token 1]
[image: token 2]
[image: token 3]

As the snippets show my session token keeps changing but does not update in the database.

### Update

Before the Laravel redirects the auth check passes but is not yet saved, after redirect session token changes and auth check fails. So from what I can tell something is causing my session token to continuously change after redirects.

Comment: please let me know if i can improve or provide more information for this, as its a serious problem right now with go live set for tomorrow been trying to fix this for about a week now.

Comment: Is it the laravel authorization or a custom one?

Comment: @dparoli its the laravel auth using make::auth command

Comment: Session driver?

Comment: session driver is database currently, also tried file

Comment: Fresh laravel install, auth enabled, session in database ad I have no problem at all. Have you custom middlware or did something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197798/discussion-between-jelly-bean-and-dparoli).

Comment: @dparoli, please see previous comment. also have checked one of your answers as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877799/laravel-global-middleware-cant-get-session/42877954#42877954

Comment: Can you paste phpinfo() related to sessions? And how are you testing your request: browser, postman, automated tests? How do you dump the array containing the _token key?
That problem might as well be a CSRF issue, because of the "_token" variable in the debug output that changes on each request and the 419 error usually dictates a CSRF verification error (token mismatch or not passed at all). It might be worth to check this as well

Comment: @mdexp will update tomorrow when i get into the office, but I know that its not the csrf token, the problem is that the session token keeps changing which causes authorization to keep failing. testing with dd(); on the page after login screen

Answer (score 0):

My problem was fixed by assigning false value to: SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE in config/session.php:

`'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),`

Comment: was your session token changing all the time on redirects? will be sure to try your solution regardless

Comment: Yes, it was filling the sessions folder indefinitely and returning 419 error. Even when I switched to database, same thing happened